# Content type data becomes the field label for another content type

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7, and on my Drupal website I've created a content type. This content type has 2 fields: field name, and code. I need to create another content type, and (on this content type) fields based on the data of the "Name" field of the previous content type.

For example:

- Content type ABC: content

  ```
  Name  | Code
  AAAAA | A
  ABABA | B
  ACACA | C
  ```
- Content type DEF: fields

  - AAAAA (widget: textfield)
  - ABABA (widget: textfield)
  - ACACA (widget: textfield)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:

Comment: it's not what i need. I need that the label of the field become dynamic. Thank you btw.

Comment: @user1814734, in that case you should try `hook_form_alter` and alter the element titles accordingly.

Comment: But, the dynamic label is not only for one field. For example: i have 2 content type product and invoice. Then i need to add all product name as the field label on content type invoice. So if on content type product i have iphone, ipad, ipod, then on content type invoice, the form will be: iphone: *textfield* ipad: *textfield* ipod: *textfield*.

Comment: @user1814734, if you have a relation its possible with form alter, if not its never possible or you need to write tons of `if()`s

Comment: i've updated my comment above, is that possible to get result as i mention?